# @import browser compatibility 2013

Tags: css

I've been reading up about responsive design and am going to start implementing a new CSS set-up on my site. This has lead me to thinking about the best way to call all these different CSS files. I'll have a different CSS for different screen widths.

I am debating two options:

1. connecting to all the files from each web page with LINK tags. My only problem with this is the ongoing maintenance (and having to add all these links to start with); I know this isn't the end of the world but seems a little bit intensive on the maintenance side.
2. the other way would to have just one LINK tag on each web page, pointing at a 'feeder' CSS. This 'feeder' CSS file would include all the links to my other CSS files using @imports. This would mean maintenance would be a breeze. I could add/re-order/delete the CSS files in just one place for the entire site. Great!

However this leads on to compatibility of the @import function [or lack of it in older browsers].

I've looked around and the articles I've seen have been at least a couple of years old.

So, to get to the nub: what percentage of browsers that are being used now [July 2013] support this and can I safely forget about the browsers that wont be able to interpret @import?

If not, what can I do to keep maintenance of CSS files down to a minimum. (Something more elegant than "find and replace on current site").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of worrying about `@import`s, you should just combine and minify all of your CSS files that cannot be served via a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-84e599dcbd6c60fa0af76aaa18a5d75f.css" />
```

It'll load faster, use up less bandwidth, and will work on any browser that supports stylesheets.

There are many ways to do this. If you're not using any web framework (or are using Node.js), take a look at [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started).

As for your actual question, unless you're planning to support browsers older than IE5.5, [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) will work just fine. But I strongly recommend the minified stylesheet approach.

Comment: the answer just gos along with what i said in point 1, [which im  inclined to agree with] but doesnt give any reasons why or an alternative for maintaining large amounts of css files. i thought it was a bit lazy/trigger happy.

Comment: @as_bold_as_love: *this has lead me to thinking about the best way to call all these different CSS file*. You asked for the best way, so I'm giving it to you. Take a look at how StackOverflow does it. A single, versioned, and minified glob of CSS without any `@import`s.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your help. sometimes its good to ask questions.

Comment: thnx for updating your answer Blender. thats a lot clearer. i wasnt familiar with the term 'minimize' before, in terms of CSS, so you've put me on to a good thing there. thx

Comment: ok, so one last question. assuming we are talking about 'small business' websites [around 10 pages] with small traffic, and assuming you were going to put on a message for older browser user to say your sites not catered for [like a lot of the big sites do] would you agree that from a maintenance point of view [we have a lot of these sites] the @import route might be a better option?

Comment: this article seems to give some pretty good reasons not for using @import. issues such as files been downloaded sequetially instead of in paralel in certain browsers and knock bad effects with javaScript http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/ - ill think ill stir clear for now and just have to bite the bullet on the poor maintenance issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to actually say that the accepted answer, now in 2016, is not necessarily the correct one-- for a couple of reasons:

1) HTTP 2.0 is becoming the majority-used protocol version in industrialized countries outside of China (thanks, old IE), and will soon be considered the industry standard (if it's not already). This means that support for connection multiplexing and header caching eliminates the need to combine files into one; in fact, at the Fluent Conference in SFO last year the HTTP2 presenter actually argued that splitting things like CSS and images into multiple files will actually be better due to HTTP's superior ability to utilize more bandwidth due to longer connection times.

2) Because of all this front-end automation in CSS like SASS and LESS, you end up much more likely to break the IE 5-9 4095 selector limitation. This is a little known bug because until now people rarely exceeded that number of selectors in a single sheet; however, on enterprise sites this is becoming a common thing. Basically, any sheet with more than 4095 selectors will still be read in, however the browsers will simply silently fail to render any rules after that.

This isn't to say that minifying into one file is *bad*, however, the other approach of splitting is actually *no longer bad either*, and in fact, in certain cases is either *necessary* or even *better* depending on project needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some stats about browsers http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

For responsive css I would use media queries, it wont affect older browsers, and work great for devices that are going to need the responsive css (mobile devices)

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: *From the statistics below (collected from W3Schools' log-files over a period of ten years)*. I don't think this is representative of the general population.

Comment: yeah, media quieres are essential for responsive design, but they can be used on @imports aswell. the real question im asking here is if its viablie to forget LINK tags yet? hopefully, in terms of maintenance, it will be at some point. Or is the speed difference a real issue????