# Generating a standalone package with Angular-Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm building a web app in Angular2 using Angular-Cli.
We are about to deploy it in production so we are trying to build it.

As we are not going to use Node as web server we would need to use the standalone bundle (dist folder) generated by

> ng build --prod --aot

Right now if we do that the browser loads all assets (JS, CSS, images, etc) correctly (no 404) and the app loads (it's fully usable). The thing is that it doesn't render the CSS style, it's just an unstyled HTML doc.

The strange thing is that if the app is serve by doing

> ng serve

then only some styles are loaded.

Any clue of what may be happening?

Versions:

- Angular2: 2.2.1
- Angular-Cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
- Typescript: 2.0.10

Thanks!

EDIT:
Example of the CSS not being included:

```
.timeline-icon {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.btn-clear-timeline {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}    
.panel-no-mb {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: @JayChase the CSS is included in the bundle that is generated. Something is happening that prevents the browser from loading the styles and displaying the page correctly.

Comment: @Mital Gajjar I'm able to generate that folder, It just doesn't run correctly when loaded in the browser.

Comment: Try setting "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" on your components? Also double check the HTTP response for the css files, is it definitely Css (and not .less or sass), is the response content type "text/css".?

Comment: @Baconbeastnz Setting the encapsulation didn't fixed the problem. I inspected the network request and the CSS files have the correct content type.

Comment: Sometimes on some servers you have to change mimeType of json/css files. Where did you (what kind of server) deploy site?

Comment: @MichałIgnaszewski thanks for the suggestion but it didn't worked. I'm using the Django dev server for the moment. Then We'll use Nginx. I configured the server to force all css files to be served as text/css but still no luck.

Comment: try a light server on the dist folder.

npm install -g lite-server =>

ng build --prod =>

cd dist =>

lite-server =>,

--------
If that doesn't work something is wrong with the build or the code..

Comment: @JohanBlomgren sure I'll add an example of the CSS to the question. I @ import various css files in the styles.css and then include that file in the styles sections of the angular-cli config file. I tried including the files individually and also directly in the HTML with no luck.

Comment: @JohanBlomgren lite server didn't worked with the dist folder. How can I debug what may be wrong? I started a new projectvwith a subset of the components. I'll try to isolate the problem

Comment: @Martin sorry, can't reproduce. I've @-imported less files in styles.css, put them in different folders, overridden styles in *.component.css.. and everything just works :(

Comment: @JohanBlomgren yeah, I just decided to step over angular-cli and use webpack directly and it started working. I have to test a little more but it looks like it's all right. Thanks!!

Comment: Is the link to the css file in the bundle generated html correct?

Comment: @SouparnoMajumder yes, there's no 404 error when loading the page.

Comment: @Skeptor we ended up not using Angular-cli. We switched to pure webpack and got it all running.

Comment: I was curious as to whether @import was supported .across all browsers.  It was.. Came across this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928732/import-browser-compatibility-2013 They mentioned Grunt tasks and using CDN for minified CSS to save on bandwidth. Good to see you got it working with Webpack...

Comment: @Martin You should answer your own question with the solution - so question isn't coming up as unanswered...

Comment: @JGFMK the thing is that this isn't answered. We solved the problem by switching to pure webpack and not using Angular-CLI

Comment: @Martin I was Googling on something totally separate that took me into a Github CLI bug page... In it someone used an npm install command with @ webpack where you'd normally use @ latest... Have never seen this syntax before... Maybe you can use CLI to setup a webpack project have never tried. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1974#issuecomment-245673131

Comment: Have you tried to use a newer CLI?

Comment: @BogdanC at the moment we used the new one. Then we switched to Webpack.